# How to implement Ehlers Homodyne Discriminator in Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, discriminator

I want to include a dynamic 'lookback period' for my stock indicators for a given time period entry. I've previously implemented Ehler's Homodyne Discriminator using a [rolling window](https://www.quantconnect.com/docs/algorithm-reference/rolling-window); every time a new datapoint comes into my algorithm, the discriminator is recalculated (but retains memory of prior calculations...see below). I would rather determine the period using Pandas as it seems to be a faster method of implementing data processing over large datasets.

Note that I encounter data two ways: first, historical data is generated in bulk; and second, data comes in 1 minute at a time and will be added to the historical data for reprocessing.

The issues I face are:

1. Calculations are dependent on the at-index value of period, and period depends on the other calculations (see original script). However the calculations using pandas are currently done in bulk so the data never changes over time which it should.
2. The dataframe includes values for multiple assets (MultiIndex) and so I currently process the discriminator once per asset; is there a way I can run this once and let Pandas do the grouping?
3. Should I simply reprocess the entire dataset every time new data comes in, or should I do away with the benefits of Pandas and just iterate through each new row and use my old script?

---

Historical Data:

```
                            close   high     low     open     volume
symbol time                                                           
SPY    2019-06-07 15:41:00  288.03  288.060  287.98  288.030  132296.0
       2019-06-07 15:42:00  288.04  288.060  287.96  288.035  103635.0
       2019-06-07 15:43:00  288.15  288.160  288.04  288.045  144841.0
       2019-06-07 15:44:00  288.10  288.190  288.09  288.150  166086.0
       2019-06-07 15:45:00  287.93  288.120  287.93  288.100  145304.0
       2019-06-07 15:46:00  287.77  287.935  287.75  287.935  253202.0
       2019-06-07 15:47:00  287.86  287.870  287.76  287.760  140996.0
       2019-06-07 15:48:00  287.78  287.865  287.76  287.860  178082.0
       2019-06-07 15:49:00  287.83  287.855  287.62  287.790  631133.0
       2019-06-07 15:50:00  287.83  287.915  287.78  287.825  279326.0
```

Original Script (self.Value is actual period). If you don't use QuantConnect, I'm sure you could just replace all RollingWindows with arrays with reversed data or reverse the references. In this script, `Update` is called every time a new row is created in the dataframe:

```
class HomodyneDiscriminatorPeriodOld():
    Values = RollingWindow[int](2)
    SmoothedPeriod = RollingWindow[float](2)
    Smooth = RollingWindow[float](7)
    Detrend = RollingWindow[float](7)
    Source = RollingWindow[float](4)
    I1 = RollingWindow[float](7)
    I2 = RollingWindow[float](7)
    Q1 = RollingWindow[float](7)
    Q2 = RollingWindow[float](7)
    Re = RollingWindow[float](2)
    Im = RollingWindow[float](2)

    def FillWindows(self, *args, value=0):
        for window in args:
            for i in range(window.Size):
                window.Add(value)

    def __init__(self, period=1):
        self.Value = period
        self.Period = period
        # Start with history
        self.FillWindows(self.Smooth, self.SmoothedPeriod, self.Detrend, self.I1, self.I2, self.Q1, self.Q2, self.Re, self.Im)
        self.FillWindows(self.Values, value=self.Value)


    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.Value)


    def Weighted(self, first, second, percent=0.2):
        return percent * first + (1 - percent) * second


    def Quadrature(self, window):
        C1 = 0.0962
        C2 = 0.5769
        C3 = self.Period * 0.075 + 0.54
        return (window[0] * C1 + window[2] * C2 - window[4] * C2 - window[6] * C1) * C3


    def Update(self, data):
        self.Source.Add((data.High + data.Low) / 2)
        if not self.Source.IsReady: return self.Value

        #
        # --- Start the Homodyne Discriminator Caculations
        #
        # Mutable Variables (non-series)
        self.Smooth.Add((self.Source[0] * 4.0 + self.Source[1] * 3.0 + self.Source[2] * 2.0 + self.Source[3]) / 10.0)
        self.Detrend.Add(self.Quadrature(self.Smooth))

        # Compute InPhase and Quadrature components
        self.Q1.Add(self.Quadrature(self.Detrend))
        self.I1.Add(self.Detrend[3])

        # Advance Phase of I1 and Q1 by 90 degrees
        jI = self.Quadrature(self.I1)
        jQ = self.Quadrature(self.Q1)

        # Phaser addition for 3 bar averaging and 
        # Smooth i and q components before applying discriminator
        self.I2.Add(self.Weighted(self.I1[0] - jQ, self.I2[0]))
        self.Q2.Add(self.Weighted(self.Q1[0] + jI, self.Q2[0]))

        # Extract Homodyne Discriminator
        self.Re.Add(self.Weighted(self.I2[0] * self.I2[1] + self.Q2[0] * self.Q2[1], self.Re[0]))
        self.Im.Add(self.Weighted(self.I2[0] * self.Q2[1] - self.Q2[0] * self.I2[1], self.Im[0]))

        # Calculate the period
        period = ((math.pi * 2) / math.atan(self.Im[0] / self.Re[0])) if (self.Re[0] != 0 and self.Im[0] != 0) else 0
        period = min(max(max(min(period, 1.5 * self.Period), 0.6667 * self.Period), 6), 50)
        self.Period = self.Weighted(period, self.Period)
        self.SmoothedPeriod.Add(self.Weighted(self.Period, self.SmoothedPeriod[0], 0.33))
        self.Value = round(self.SmoothedPeriod[0] * 0.5 - 1)
        if self.Value < 1: self.Value = 1
        self.Values.Add(self.Value)

        return self.Value
```

Pandas Script. `Update` is currently only called once after bulk import of historical data. I have yet to implement a walk-forward method of calculation as indicated by Q3 if it's even required:

```
class HomodyneDiscriminatorPeriod():


    def Weighted(self, series, other=None, percent=0.2):
        if other is None: other = series
        return percent * series + (1 - percent) * other


    def Quadrature(self, series):
        C1 = 0.0962
        C2 = 0.5769
        C3 = self.Frame.period * 0.075 + 0.54
        return (series * C1 + series.shift(2) * C2 - series.shift(4) * C2 - series.shift(6) * C1) * C3


    def Update(self, frame):
        # Add period column to timeframe's dataframe
        frame['period'] = 1

        # Initialize internal dataframe with same structure
        # as timeframe's dataframe but without original columns
        self.Frame = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(frame)
        self.Frame.drop(frame.columns, axis=1)
        self.Frame['period'] = 1
        self.Frame['smoothed_period'] = 1
        self.Frame['i2'] = 0
        self.Frame['q2'] = 0
        self.Frame['re'] = 0
        self.Frame['im'] = 0

        # Shorthand references
        period = self.Frame['period']
        smoothed_period = self.Frame['smoothed_period']
        i2 = self.Frame['i2']
        q2 = self.Frame['q2']
        re = self.Frame['re']
        im = self.Frame['im']

        #
        # --- Start the Homodyne Discriminator Caculations
        #
        # Mutable Variables (non-series)
        hl2 = (frame.high + frame.low) / 2
        smooth = (hl2 * 4.0 + hl2.shift(1) * 3.0 + hl2.shift(2) * 2.0 + hl2.shift(3)) / 10.0
        detrend = self.Quadrature(smooth)

        # Compute InPhase and Quadrature components
        q1 = self.Quadrature(detrend)
        i1 = detrend.shift(3)

        # Advance Phase of I1 and Q1 by 90 degrees
        ji = self.Quadrature(i1)
        jq = self.Quadrature(q1)

        # Phaser addition for 3 bar averaging and
        # smooth i and q components before applying discriminator
        i2 = self.Weighted(i1 - jq)
        q2 = self.Weighted(q1 + ji)

        # Extract Homodyne Discriminator
        re = self.Weighted(i2 * i2.shift(1) + q2 * q2.shift(1))
        im = self.Weighted(i2 * q2.shift(1) - q2 * i2.shift(1))

        # Calculate the period
        # TODO: Use 360 or 2 * np.pi???? Official doc says 360...
        _period = (2 * np.pi / np.arctan(im / re)).clip(upper=1.5 * period, lower=0.6667 * period).clip(upper=50, lower=6)
        period = self.Weighted(_period, period)
        smoothed_period = self.Weighted(period, smoothed_period, 0.33)
        return (smoothed_period * 0.5 - 1).round().clip(lower=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think that recalculating the homodyne filter for the entire dataset each time a new bar became available would be much too expensive.  Recall, most of Ehler's cycle filters are determined recursively -- and the homodyne looks back more bars than the supersmoother or high-pass filter.  Given this, most trading platforms simply hold the resulting arrays in memory, and then just pick off the array elements a few bars back to calculate results for each new bar.

Note that none of the platforms go all the way back to the beginning and calculate the resulting output arrays for the entire time series when a new bar becomes available.  If Pandas is that fast, then this may not be an issue.   But in theory, I would not do that computationally, since it would be duplicative (unnecessary) computation.  In other words, no matter how fast a platform is, why would you calculate the same array elements over and over again thousands of times within the time series, when you only need to look back about 6 bars for most Ehlers filters, and a few more for the homodyne when each new bar becomes available?

Comment: Ideally I would implement a 'bulk operation' in Pandas for historical data and then when my app updates on new bar data, I would iteratively process it considering the data up until that point is now stored in a dataframe. The slow way is to iterate over all the data as compared to Pandas vector processing.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06